# Location Settings Dialog shown twice OR how to detect that dialog is shown\closed

Tags: android, google-play-services, locationmanager

I want to show Location Settings Dialog every time when activity in foreground and Location turned off, in onResume().

The issue: every time will be created new Settings Dialog without destroying previous one and I have stack from dialogues. By back button or by cancel button will be shown another Settings Dialog that was shown before.

Another issue if that when location is enabled from notification bar dialog still shown and I can't close it.

```
public class CheckLocationActivity extends FloatingActionsMenuActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        showDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
            googleApiClient.connect();


            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            //**************************
//            builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
            //**************************


            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    CheckLocationActivity.this, 1000);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

}nSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                            // a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                status.startResolutionForResult(CheckLocationActivity.this, 1000);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

}
```

Comment: you solved your problem?

Comment: it was not solved

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean to check if the dialog as being already shown. Remember to persist in the boolean in your bundle outstate and load in onCreate so that it doesn't get lost upon rotation change.

Comment: With this solution you will show dialog only once, when activity created first time. After dialog shown, Boolean will be always true. Required: to show dialig each time when onResume called.